each loop button worpress
<?php 
function custom_dbnew_link()
{
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'personeellijst';
// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ 
    $kantoor1 = $retrieved_data->naam;
    
}   



    
return '
<div id="roosterhtml" style="display:none;">
<div id="testnav" class="navfoto"><div class="Personeel">Personeel  fotos voor <div class="perfirstname" id="roosterfotos"></div></div><div id="closefoto" class="closefoto">opslaan</div></div>
<div id="testnavcopy" style="display:none;" class="navfoto"><div class="Personeel">Personeel  fotos voor <div class="perfirstname" id="roosterfotos2"></div></div><div id="closefoto2" class="closefoto">opslaan</div></div>

<div class="fotobuttons2">
<div class="buttonsarchief"><div id="newmembersbutton" class="buttonmembers active">In dienst</div>
<div id="oldmembersbutton" class="buttonmembers">Uit Dienst (Inval)</div>
<div id="addmembersbutton" class="buttonmembers">Nieuwe personeel Toevoegen</div></div>
</div>

<div id="newmembers" class="fotobuttons">
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="'. $kantoor1 .'" class="pasfotoselect"><div class="namediv leeg"><img decoding="async" src="/wp-content/personeel/pasfoto/'. $kantoor1 .'.jpg " class="personeelpasfoto" alt="nophoto-laki"><div class="pername">'. $kantoor1 .'</div></div></button>


</div>

</div>
<script src="/wp-content/uploads/personeeldatabase.js"></script>
';
}
add_shortcode('custom_dbnew', 'custom_dbnew_link');

?>

how can i loop the <button> the $kantoor1 is in database whit diferent names now it shows the last name in row it is a wordpress website i searched google and watches videos on yuotube

You should use like below
<?php 

    function custom_dbnew_link(){
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'personeellijst';
        // this will get the data from your table
        $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );

        $returnHtml = '';
        foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ 
            $kantoor1 = $retrieved_data->naam;
            

            $returnHtml .= '<div id="roosterhtml" style="display:none;">
            <div id="testnav" class="navfoto"><div class="Personeel">Personeel  fotos voor <div class="perfirstname" id="roosterfotos"></div></div><div id="closefoto" class="closefoto">opslaan</div></div>
            <div id="testnavcopy" style="display:none;" class="navfoto"><div class="Personeel">Personeel  fotos voor <div class="perfirstname" id="roosterfotos2"></div></div><div id="closefoto2" class="closefoto">opslaan</div></div>

            <div class="fotobuttons2">
            <div class="buttonsarchief"><div id="newmembersbutton" class="buttonmembers active">In dienst</div>
            <div id="oldmembersbutton" class="buttonmembers">Uit Dienst (Inval)</div>
            <div id="addmembersbutton" class="buttonmembers">Nieuwe personeel Toevoegen</div></div>
            </div>

            <div id="newmembers" class="fotobuttons">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" id="'. $kantoor1 .'" class="pasfotoselect"><div class="namediv leeg"><img decoding="async" src="/wp-content/personeel/pasfoto/'. $kantoor1 .'.jpg " class="personeelpasfoto" alt="nophoto-laki"><div class="pername">'. $kantoor1 .'</div></div></button>
            </div>
            </div>';
        }  
        $returnHtml .= '<script src="/wp-content/uploads/personeeldatabase.js"></script>';
        return $returnHtml;
    }
    add_shortcode('custom_dbnew', 'custom_dbnew_link');
?>


this works but how can i loop the '. $kantoor1 .' the are several members in the database now i got this code

what you mean by how can i loop? already in for loop

Do you want loop only for the button?
